# Rendering Oval Shape on a PDF document using Xfinium.Graphics

Tags: java, c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently passing a **json object**, and want to be able to draw an oval shape around some values of the **json object** in a PDF file e.g

```
 {"Applicant": 
   {
     "Insurance1":"Gold",
     "Insurance2":"Platinum"
   }
 }
```

[image: Renderd on PDF like this]
What is required is that the **height** and **width** of the text should determine the size of the oval shape. I am also reading the PDF file from a remote service.
I need help on how to achieve this with ***Xfinium.Graphics***

Answer (score 0):

i was able to draw an oval shape on a pdf document(with [Xfinium.Pdf](https://www.xfiniumpdf.com/)) by using the code below

```
 PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();



        PdfStandardFont font = new PdfStandardFont();

        PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

        double checkLeft = 50;

        double checkTop = 50;

        double checkWidth = 100;

        double checkHeight = 20;

        PdfStandardFont font = new PdfStandardFont();



        PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

        BuildCheckBox1("check1", "1", "Checked 1", "Unchecked 1", font, page, new PdfVisualRectangle(checkLeft, checkTop, checkWidth, checkHeight));

        checkTop += 25;

        BuildCheckBox1("check2", "2", "Checked 2", "Unchecked 2", font, page, new PdfVisualRectangle(checkLeft, checkTop, checkWidth, checkHeight));

        checkTop += 25;

        BuildCheckBox1("check3", "2", "Checked 3", "Unchecked 3", font, page, new PdfVisualRectangle(checkLeft, checkTop, checkWidth, checkHeight));

        checkTop += 25;



        PdfStringAppearanceOptions sao = new PdfStringAppearanceOptions();

        sao.Brush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Black);

        sao.Font = font;

        PdfStringLayoutOptions slo = new PdfStringLayoutOptions();

        slo.X = checkLeft + checkWidth / 2;

        slo.Y = checkTop + checkHeight / 2;

        slo.HorizontalAlign = PdfStringHorizontalAlign.Center;

        slo.VerticalAlign = PdfStringVerticalAlign.Middle;

        page.Graphics.DrawString("Option", sao, slo);

        BuildCheckBox2("check4", "4", page, new PdfVisualRectangle(checkLeft, checkTop, checkWidth, checkHeight));



        document.Save("Sample_OvalCheckBox.pdf");



    private void BuildCheckBox1(string name, string exportValue, string checkedText, string uncheckedText, PdfFont font, PdfPage page, PdfVisualRectangle location)

    {

        PdfCheckBoxField checkBoxField = new PdfCheckBoxField(name);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckBoxWidget).ExportValue = exportValue;

        page.Fields.Add(checkBoxField);

        checkBoxField.Widgets[0].VisualRectangle = location;

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).CheckStyle = PdfCheckStyle.Check;



        double lineWidth = 2;

        PdfPen redPen = new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.Red, lineWidth);

        PdfPen grayPen = new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.LightGray, lineWidth / 2);

        grayPen.DashPattern = new double[] { 1, 1 };

        PdfBrush pinkBrush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.LightPink);

        PdfStringAppearanceOptions sao = new PdfStringAppearanceOptions();

        sao.Brush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Black);

        sao.Font = font;

        PdfStringLayoutOptions slo = new PdfStringLayoutOptions();

        slo.X = location.Width / 2;

        slo.Y = location.Height / 2;

        slo.HorizontalAlign = PdfStringHorizontalAlign.Center;

        slo.VerticalAlign = PdfStringVerticalAlign.Middle;



        PdfAnnotationAppearance checkedAppearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance(location.Width, location.Height);

        checkedAppearance.Graphics.DrawRoundRectangle(redPen, pinkBrush,

            lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, location.Width - lineWidth, location.Height - lineWidth,

            location.Height - lineWidth, location.Height - lineWidth);

        checkedAppearance.Graphics.DrawString(checkedText, sao, slo);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).CheckedStateNormalAppearance = checkedAppearance;

        PdfAnnotationAppearance uncheckedAppearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance(location.Width, location.Height);

        uncheckedAppearance.Graphics.DrawRoundRectangle(grayPen, pinkBrush,

            lineWidth / 4, lineWidth / 4, location.Width - lineWidth / 2, location.Height - lineWidth / 2,

            location.Height - lineWidth / 2, location.Height - lineWidth / 2);

        uncheckedAppearance.Graphics.DrawString(uncheckedText, sao, slo);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).UncheckedStateNormalAppearance = uncheckedAppearance;

    }



    private void BuildCheckBox2(string name, string exportValue, PdfPage page, PdfVisualRectangle location)

    {

        PdfCheckBoxField checkBoxField = new PdfCheckBoxField(name);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckBoxWidget).ExportValue = exportValue;

        page.Fields.Add(checkBoxField);

        checkBoxField.Widgets[0].VisualRectangle = location;

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).CheckStyle = PdfCheckStyle.Check;



       double lineWidth = 2;

        PdfPen redPen = new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.Red, lineWidth);

        PdfPen grayPen = new PdfPen(PdfRgbColor.LightGray, lineWidth / 2);

        grayPen.DashPattern = new double[] { 1, 1 };



        PdfAnnotationAppearance checkedAppearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance(location.Width, location.Height);

        checkedAppearance.Graphics.DrawRoundRectangle(redPen,

            lineWidth / 2, lineWidth / 2, location.Width - lineWidth, location.Height - lineWidth,

            location.Height - lineWidth, location.Height - lineWidth);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).CheckedStateNormalAppearance = checkedAppearance;

        PdfAnnotationAppearance uncheckedAppearance = new PdfAnnotationAppearance(location.Width, location.Height);

        uncheckedAppearance.Graphics.DrawRoundRectangle(grayPen,

            lineWidth / 4, lineWidth / 4, location.Width - lineWidth / 2, location.Height - lineWidth / 2,

            location.Height - lineWidth / 2, location.Height - lineWidth / 2);

        (checkBoxField.Widgets[0] as PdfCheckWidget).UncheckedStateNormalAppearance = uncheckedAppearance;

    }
```

the vector image will look something like this : [image: Oval Shape]